# Can you refine my routes and ajax requests?(php/laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am a newbie laravel user and tried to write my code with tutorials and docs.
When I try to open the site a loading animation occurs and after that, the menu and contentt split  into either side of the page.
I want only to change content division   when I click menu buttons.

These are my routes.php:

```
Route::controller(Controller::detect());
Route::get('articles', array('uses'=>'articles@index'));
Route::get('articles/(:any)', array('as'=>'article','uses'=>'articles@view'));
Route::get('abouts', array('as'=>'abouts','uses'=>'abouts@index'));
```

This is my  default.blade.php menu part:

```
<div id="sidebar-content">
   <ul id="menu">
       <li class="current"><a href="<?php echo URL::to('articles'); ?>">ANASAYFA</a></li>
       <li><a href="<?php echo URL::to('abouts'); ?>">HAKKIMIZDA</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Are the links correct here ?

My ajax.js

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#sidebar-content ul li a").click( function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#content').load(this.href);
        console.log('This href =='+this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

When I click links, I get a loading animation and the content is not shown.
This is my articles controller :

```
class Articles_Controller extends Base_Controller {
    public $restful = true;
    public $layout = 'layouts.default';

    public function get_index(){
        $this->layout->title = "Anasayfa";
        $this->layout->content = View::make('articles.index')->with('articles',Article::order_by('id')->get());
    }
}
```

These are the console.logs :

```
GET http://localhost/~ytsejam/laravel/public/index.php/abouts  jquery.min.js (line 4)
This href ==http://localhost/~ytsejam/laravel/public/index.php/abouts   ajax.js (line 6)
GET http://localhost/~ytsejam/laravel/public/js/basic.js?_=13446   jquery.min.js (line 4)
GET http://localhost/~ytsejam/laravel/public/index.php/abouts jquery.min.js (line 5)
This href ==http://localhost/~ytsejam/laravel/public/index.php/abouts ajax.js (line 6)
GET http://localhost/~ytsejam/laravel/public/index.php/abouts jquery.min.js (line 5)
This href ==http://localhost/~ytsejam/laravel/public/index.php/abouts jquery.min.js (line 7)
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the reason why your menu and content split. Probably you could re-read your Javascript, because it looks to me  like the splitting problem is located there.

As for your links. If I read the documentation http://laravel.com/docs/routing, I would expect the links to be `URL::to_route('abouts')` and `URL::to_route('articles')`, because you use named routes.

And you are using the blade engine (because your file is named default.*blade*.php). Therefore you could write `{{ URL::to_route('abouts') }}` in stead of `<?php echo URL::to_route('abouts'); ?>`

Hope this is of any help,
Hendrik Jan

Comment: Animation is loaded when entering the page. So after page splits into each side. That is the way I want, I dont want to page to be reloaded each time I click links.